# Algorithm to identify rearrangements between two sequences of unique values

Tags: algorithms, subsequences

I have two sequences, seq1 and seq2, each consisting of unique values. Values can appear in seq1 or seq2 which do not appear in the other, and these values can appear in any order. How do I identify which values have been moved in seq2, such that values appear earlier or later in seq2 relative to the values in seq1? To visually describe the problem, any value whose arrow from seq1 to seq2 overlaps with another should be marked as moved, and is bracketed.

[image: A B C D to B D C]

In the image above, C and D should be marked as moved.

[image: A B C D E to A D C B E]

In the image above, B and D (and probably C) should be marked as moved, though I’m mainly interested in the start and end values which have been moved.

[image: A B C D E to A D E]

In the above image, no values should be marked as moved.

[image: A B C D E to A D E C]

However, if we add C to the end of the second sequence, D, E and C should be marked as moved.

[image: A B C to A D E F B C]

New values should trivially be marked as moved, but the values around them should not.

Is there a way identify moved values with just a single traversal through both sequences? Either the canonical name of this problem or pseudocode would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you define under what conditions you consider a node to have been moved?  I think we need a more careful specification. Examples are not a substitute for a general definition.  I don't know what "a node appears earlier or later in seq2 relative to the values in seq1" means.  You might find it helpful to use mathematics and to refer to the values or nodes with variables like $x$, $y$, etc.

Comment: It strikes me that you're not entirely clear on the problem definition.  When you mention "(and probably C)", that suggests to me that you don't have a crisp definition of what you mean by "moved".  If you don't know exactly what the task or problem statement is, we probably aren't going to be able to solve it for you.  The first step is to figure out a clear specification of your task, and probably only you can do that.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance.

Comment: Yes I suppose I have a looser definition of moved than might be required for mathematical rigor, but that’s a lot of my current struggles with figuring out the algorithm to begin with. The devil is in the specification. But I have provided a visual explanation of what I mean (lines overlapped) which I think almost everyone should grasp intuitively and I think that should be enough for knowledgable people to point me in the right direction.


None of the algorithms related to edit distance apply, because I’m working with sequences of unique values.

Comment: I don't understand why you've rejected edit distance.  Edit distance works on any pair of sequences (it still works even if the values are unique).

Comment: I don’t think any of the algorithms on the page you’ve linked to deal with unique values between pairs of sequences exclusively. Any edit distance algorithm which allows a unique value between the pairs to be deleted and inserted is incorrect.

Comment: I see.  Thanks.  In your last example, why do you want to mark D,E,C as moved rather than B,C or D,E,F?  I still think we need more of a formalization of what counts as "moved" than these three examples.  Perhaps you can list requirements that any definition would need to satisfy.

Comment: So the actual problem I’m trying to solve is keyed virtual DOM nodes in a web framework I’m working on. There are two passes done, where the internal virtual dom nodes are reordered in a pure javascript step, and then the DOM is notified of these changes with an actual array of the new DOM nodes. Children DOM nodes are responsible for removing themselves, so all the DOM update logic has to do is figure out which nodes need to be inserted before others. I guess the edit operation I am most interested in is insertBefore, which is why new nodes are marked as moved.